# Headset msbc works in 22.10 but only csvd in 23.04 (pics)

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom, microphone

since upgrading to 23.04 Bluetooth headset will only work in CSVD mode not in superior mSBC? Images demo 22.10 good behaviour 23.04 bad behaviour. These are both laptops with in built Broadcom chips,  it also repeats on a desktop on 23.04 with broadcom dongle.

If you force mSBC in 23.04 in sound dropdown the audio mic drops to internal

mysterious[22.10 sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etXoF.png)

here is the dmsg output

```
[    0.081974] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000079800000-0x000000007dffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[    0.081981] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x0000000079800000-0x000000007dffffff]
[    0.230254] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    7.592850] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.592959] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    7.592961] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.592966] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.592968] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.593064] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.750309] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.Dell Inc.-XPS 13 9350.bin failed with error -2
[    7.753311] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    7.753379] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[    8.027323] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 110
[    8.028323] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[    8.044329] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4350C5
[    8.044333] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4350C5 (003.006.007) build 0000
[    8.045772] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4350C5 'brcm/BCM4350C5-0a5c-6412.hcd' Patch
[    8.263852] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4350/8 wl0: Oct 22 2015 06:16:26 version 7.35.180.119 (r594535) FWID 01-e791c176
[    8.700394] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[    8.716370] Bluetooth: hci0: Dell DW1820A
[    8.716375] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4350C5 (003.006.007) build 0593
[    8.732650] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    9.785674] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.785680] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.785685] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.789723] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   11.564079] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   11.564089] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   11.564095] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: What results from terminal for `sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response

Comment: Can you run `bluetoothctl` in terminal before trying to switch the sound and see if any errors reported?

Comment: Hi there thanks for all your time and interest